# Getting PropertyInfo without an instance of the class

Tags: vb.net, reflection

I have started using reflection and am a bit confused about getting `PropertyInfo`.

I do something like this and it works:

```
Dim x as New MyClass
Dim prop as PropertyInfo = x.GetType.GetProperty("Name")
```

I don't understand why I must have an instance of the class in order to get a property from it. If `GetType` returns a Type object, why couldn't I just reference the type itself?

```
Dim prop as PropertyInfo = GetType(MyClass).GetProperty("Name")
```

or

```
Dim prop as PropertyInfo = MyClass.GetType.GetProperty("Name")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim prop as PropertyInfo = GetType(MyClass).GetProperty("Name")
```

That is exactly correct.

Comment: The code editor did not have a problem with this, but there was an error at runtime. I had a generic function with a `List(of T)` that was saying the `PropertyInfo` was not the same type as the `T`. Once I changed the code to the `Dim x as New MyClass` example, it worked fine.

Comment: @Origin: In that case, show us the actual code you're having a problem with. The above should _normally_ be fine.

Comment: I came across this again and tried the code this way again and it worked. There must have been some other issue the last time around.

Answer (score 0):

A safer way:

```
Dim prop as PropertyInfo = GetType(MyClass).GetProperty(NameOf(MyClass.MyProperty))
```